# Update Table and out refcursor Records Stored Procedure Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I've created a procedure inside a Oracle package. When I execute the package from TOAD I can see the updated records in output. But Same procedure when called through a console application returns 0 records. I don't know why.

May be I'm doing a rookie mistake somewhere but Please let me know what am I doing wrong here.

```
PROCEDURE TestProc( Cur_Result out sys_refcursor)
As 
begin

Update Table1 where condition-1; 
Commit;
Update Table1 where condition-2; 
Commit;

open Cur_Result for
select * from Table1;

END TestProc;
```

Calling procedure from console app with .NET code -
From TOAD - Executing the package from schema browser.
Console App - Calling the procedure like below -

```
Using conn As New OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CS").ConnectionString)
            conn.Open()
            cmd = New OracleCommand(SchemaName & "." & "TestProc", conn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("CUR_RESULT", OracleType.Cursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            da = New OracleDataAdapter(cmd)
            ds = New DataSet
            da.Fill(ds)
            ''''Do something with DataSetRecords
            conn.Close()
        End Using
```

Comment: *updated records in output* i didn't see any where displaying it. post your exact code

Comment: How are you calling this? Both in TOAD and from console.

Comment: Updated my Question above with more info.

Comment: Maybe `cmd = New OracleCommand(SchemaName & "." & "TestProc(:CUR_RESULT)", conn)`?

Comment: Use `DataTable` instead of `DataSet`. Purpose of `DataSet` is to have a collection of several `DataTables`, this is not the case in your program.

Comment: Weird thing is, If I execute the procedure or the Update statement manually from back-end and run the console application, Then I can see the updated records. My hunch something is incorrect on the back end side.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not in either of the code I mentioned, it lied somewhere else. I was using a Test script to Insert the records in the table and I missed to add Commit at the end of the script.
I recently switched from SQL Server to Oracle. Transaction handling is THE BIGGEST DIFFERENCE between oracle and SQL SERVER.
Such a doofus I am. Thanks anyway guys.

Comment: *I missed to add Commit at the end of the script*, but I can clearly see in your original question, you have `commit`